# Does "key code" command on applescript acts like a keyboard?

Tags: applescript

I'm running an applescript to automate some basic tasks on a third party software, I would like to know if the following code acts like a "real keyboard" for the third party software or if it's a different approach.

```
tell application "X" to activate
delay 0.5
tell application "System Events" to tell process "X"
    set right_arrow to 124
    repeat 10 times
        key code right_arrow using command down
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
end tell
```

Can the third party soft. knows that I'm running a "different" kind of input? or it is the same input as the keyboard does?

Comment: Some poorly-made applications won't accept key codes from applescript, so in that sense, yes, it's "different". Sorry.

Comment: otherwise is the same input as the keyboard does? the application that i'm running the script is accepting the `key code`, so it means that is the same as the keyboard?